# Is there any way to remove li last child border using only and only CSS

Tags: css

suppose i have a **ul li structure** and i want to remove **last li border** which also support in **IE 6** by using **only CSS**(use of css only is compulsory in my project).

```
<ul>
    <li>HI</li>
    <li>HI</li>
    <li>HI</li>
    <li>HI</li>
</ul>'
```

I want a such type of output which also work in IE6...
[image]

Comment: <li class="otherclasss"></li> ?

Comment: *support in IE 6*. Why did you tag this question as `css3`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After a long study i got a result that there is not a single method in CSS that removes last li border which also work in IE6......so  U have to add a class on the last li element or you use jquery to remove last li border.......

**Result:- only using CSS u can't achieve this goal..........**

Comment: but it's not remove whold last li border, it's only remove last li bottom border............but my query is to remove whole last li border...

Answer (score 1):

Since supporting IE6 is a requirement, you're going to have to get a little kludgy if you don't want to use Javascript or add a class (the preferred method).

It's not clear what look you're going for, but here's a method that preserves the bullets. This assumes the borders are defined and you want to *hide* one. You can set `overflow: hidden` on the `<ul>` and `margin-bottom: -1px` on the `<li>`. This works in IE6 just fine.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### CSS:

```css
li {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}

ul {
    overflow: hidden;
}
​​
```

#### HTML:

```html
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>        
</ul>
```

Here's another method where you simply just don't define the bottom border.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### CSS:

```css
li {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

#### HTML:

```html
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>        
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding class to the last li there is no other way since it does not support `last-selector` and `+`

And the other option which might not be by pure css but I think it will helpful is by jQuery you can use jQuery, since jQuery supports `last-child`

Try

```
$(function(){
   $("ul li:last-child").css("border","none")
})
```

and  it will support almost all the browsers

Also its not good idea to consider ie6 except there special requirement . rather facebook and many big website doesn't consider ie6 check [**Browser Statistics**](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php)  ie6 does not even hold **.5%** so I would recommended to not think about  ie6

> [image]

Comment: I don't think the `+` selector works in IE6. http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/

Comment: than javascript is way to go

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution (Tested it in IE9's quirks mode, which is equivalent to IE6, but let me know the results, I strongly believe it should work):

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    ul li{
        border:1px solid red;
    }
    ul li.lastchild{
        border-bottom: 0px; // Or use "border: 0px;" if you completely 
                            // want to remove the border
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>HI</li>
        <li>HI</li>
        <li>HI</li>
        <li class="lastchild">HI</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```